# Is there any alternative API for getcwd to get the working direcory of process

Tags: c, linux, api, system-calls, getcwd

In our application we call `getcwd(3)` to get the current working directory.

When the process starts running, if anyone deletes the directory path, then the process is running but `getcwd` API fails (returns `NULL`).

Example:
Process name is: `a.exe`   present in `/root/appl/a.exe`
after running `a.exe`, if the current working directory is deleted the `getcwd(3)` api fails.

Is there any alternative API for `getcwd(3)` to know the current working directory of a process, even if the directory path deleted?

Comment: What would expect to get back if the directory has been deleted? If you're running something as a daemon then you should probably `chdir("/");` almost immediately.

Comment: the application is deployed by creating a temp directory, after appln start running the temp folder will be deleted... hence getcwd call fails.... I need to know is any other way to know the local directory of process...[for linux system]

Comment: What do you want/expect to get back, when you're in an unlinked directory?  It has no pathname!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure what you will *do* with the results of the *current working directory* when the directory will continue to exist only as long as it is held open -- you can't create new files in the directory, and it had to be empty so it could be deleted -- but you *can* use `readlink(2)` on `/proc/self/cwd` to discover the name:

```
$ mkdir syedsma
$ cd syedsma/
$ /tmp/proccwd 
/proc/self/cwd reports: /tmp/syedsma
$ /tmp/getcwd 
getcwd: /tmp/syedsma
$ rmdir ../syedsma/
$ /tmp/getcwd
getcwd failed: No such file or directory
$ /tmp/proccwd 
/proc/self/cwd reports: /tmp/syedsma (deleted)
$
```

Here's my `getcwd.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char p[1000];
    char *r;
    r = getcwd(p, sizeof(p));
    if (!r)
        perror("getcwd failed");
    else
        printf("getcwd: %s\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

And here's my `proccwd.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char buf[PATH_MAX];

    ssize_t r = readlink("/proc/self/cwd", buf, sizeof(buf));

    if (r < 0) {
        perror("readlink /proc/self/cwd failed");
        return 1;
    } else {
        buf[PATH_MAX-1] = '\0';
        printf("/proc/self/cwd reports: %s\n", buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) is correct with his advice to `chdir("/");` if it is a daemon -- I can imagine that you might have a good reason for your program to otherwise know its current working directory, and even have an idea of what the pathname might have been if it did still exist -- but in general, you shouldn't care. The pathname `"."` will work in just about every case where it makes sense to need the current working directory, until you need to implement a `pwd` shell built-in for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  char path[256];
  char buf[BUFSIZ];

  mkdir("/tmp/foo", 0755);
  chdir("/tmp/foo");
  rmdir("/tmp/foo");

  sprintf(path, "/proc/%d/cwd", getpid());
  if (readlink(path, buf, sizeof(buf)) != -1) {
    char* stop = buf+strlen(buf)-10;
    if (!strcmp(stop, " (deleted)")) {
      *stop = 0;
    }
    printf("[%s]\n", buf);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get the $PWD environment variable and cache it in your application.